# Eclipse Photon server view not showing

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-photon

I am using eclipse photon.

I am not getting servers view. I tried in Window -> show view -> other  -> servers. But it's not coming.

Any solution for this?

Comment: did you restarted eclipse ? did you tried reset window option ?

Comment: Check the logs or try to use another perspective, it might be displayed in a place where it's to tiny to be seen.

Comment: There are different Eclipse packages. Are you sure, you have the Java EE (_Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers_) package?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try resetting the perspective?

`window -> Perspective -> Reset Perspective`

After the reset, you may want to reconfigure all that is required, since it resets to the default perspective.

Comment: Tried but still servers view is itself not showing in window -> show view

Answer (score 0):

*Photon* is the name for a *version*, it has little bearing on what's actually installed as it represents a simultaneous release of 50+ projects that you can install in any combination you want. It sounds like you want the Web Tools Platform. Instructions for installing that are at https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F .

Answer (score 0):

If you do already have Eclipse up and running, Kepler and later versions can install WTP through the Marketplace.

Otherwise, within Eclipse, go to the Help menu, choose Install New Software, and while Working With All Available Sites, choose the features you want from the Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development category. If unsure, select the Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools, JST Server Adapters, and JST Server Adapters Extensions features and proceed, allowing it to select dependencies for you. For more complete steps on installing software, consult the Workbench User Guide Task:Updating and Installing Software.